# Player ranking by categories

Tags: mysql

Imagine the `Player` table with the following structure:
`PlayerId, Date, Kills, Gold, ClassId`

I need to make ranks by classes.

The "global" ranking is ok (I came from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629538/player-ranking-by-categories-over-months/) I've made), like this:

```
SET @rownumber := 0;
SET @month := 0;

SELECT pla.event_date, 
  @rownumber := IF(@month=MONTH(pla.event_date), @rownumber + 1, 1) AS rank, 
  @month := MONTH(pla.event_date) AS month, pla.kills, pla.player_id
FROM player AS pla
INNER JOIN classes AS cla ON cla.class_id = pla.class_id
WHERE pla.event_date >= '2017-09-01' AND pla.event_date <= '2017-12-31'
ORDER BY MONTH(pla.event_date), pla.kills DESC
```

But if the top 1st global is a knight and the 2nd is a mage, when I filter for mages, he'll be the 1st.
I'm really spending some time to do it.

Can someone help me?

EDIT: the first ones are matching, but when I execute a checking query with just an order by, other players are with misleading positions.

I'm using this query to check:

```
SELECT pla.player_id, pla.kills
FROM player pla
INNER JOIN classes AS cla ON cla.class_id = pla.class_id
WHERE MONTH(pla.event_date) = 9
ORDER BY pla.event_date, pla.kills DESC
```

This show me that player with ID 7487 is a Mage in the 44th position.

But when I use the first query (the global one above) filtering by `pla.class_id = 3` (3 = mage) it results in 6 (should be 44).

Comment: add `AND job= "Mage"` to your `WHERE`

Comment: @Mawg I tried so... I thought it would be this simple, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your schema? (`DESCRIBE TABLE player`) - and maybe  also that previous query

Comment: @Leonardo then you should include in your question what you have tried and what the error message or unexpected behaviour was. Consider adding sample data to demonstrate the issue. Otherwise I must agree with Mawg: you only need to to add another filter to your where clause.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Isn't that just a matter of doing `SELECT FROM (your previous query) WHERE class_id = 3` ?